# Does the average user understand the standard HTML multiple select box?

Tags: website-design, forms, html, multi-selection

If I want the user to select one or more items the HTML symantecally correct form element would be `<select multiple>`.

[So the code would be:](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/vuXwG/)

```
<select multiple id="sel">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Which looks like this:[image: multiple select widget].

The user can choose multiple elements by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking items.

This is the standard widget used by browsers, but is this the best way to display this kind of input? Do users understand it?

I could add instructions, but in my opinion if it needs instructions like that it's probably a bad design. Is there a good alternative? Maybe a JavaScript widget that replaces it?

Comment: http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In short: No, average users don't understand that.

You could either just show all options with checkboxes or try something fancy like a dropdown with checkboxes ([example](http://www.omegawatches.com/watchfinder), see features dropdown). This would have to be tested though.

Hope that helps, Phil

Comment: We use Jira to record bugs.  Our techie support team and developers still mess up selecting items from list boxes, usually removing the previous selection by mistake.

Comment: +1, normal users don't know. When you don't need to scroll, a hint like *"Hold down Ctrl to select multiple items"* sometimes is enough, but it's still not user friendly. When you need to scroll, it's bad bad bad bad.

Answer (score 5):

This pops up quite frequently in discussions, but I'm not sure if a definitive alternative has been found yet. Previous UXExchange / StackExchange discussions might give you some ideas:

[What is the best UI for multi-selecting from a list?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-best-ui-for-multi-select-from-a-list)

[Examples / best practices for dropdown menus with checkboxes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3812/examples-best-practices-for-dropdown-menus-with-checkboxes)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.suumit.com/projects/bsmSelect/examples/index.html

That is, by far, my favorite implementation of 'preferred' functionality for multiple select.  It's drop-down based instead of list as you describe.  The selections aren't checkboxed, which is really hard to handle for any list over like 6 values--you can't see everything you've checked at one time!  It's better than quite a few that I've seen, that put the selections in the input field--you quickly run out of space in the input field, and this is useless.

I've seen some that do '3 selections', which again is useless--I need to know what I've selected.  To me, this fulfills all criteria for usability:

- allow user to see immediately what they have selected
- allow user to continue to see what they have selected
- allow them to remove an incorrect selection
- allow them to 'filter' the list by typing partial match
- minimize screen real estate with basic, unfilled control

Comment: This is best solution ever. By the way, original article on that here: http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/

Answer (score 1):

Phil is right.
You could also use the same widget but remove the use of the CTRL/shift key. That would be a fairly self documenting solution if the checkboxes turn out to be unsuitable.